# IONIC2 Conseguir datos POST

Tags: angularjs, ionic, post

Necesito enviar por post un id de usuario y recoger la información necesaria del servidor (la parte del servidor ya funciona) y devuelve un JSON. La mayor parte de los problemas los he tenido con las cors pero a pesar de haber buscado, no he encontrado la solución.

```
var link : String = "DIRECCION/PHP";

this.http.post(link.toString(), "HOLA=HOLA").subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  },
  error=> {
    console.error(error);
  },
  () =>
  {

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema puede estar en los parámetros que le estas enviando, prueba a mandarle un json. Y si la petición necesita cabeceras no olvides mandárselas también.

```
obj = {
   hola: 'hola'
}
var link : String = "DIRECCION/PHP";

 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
 headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

this.http.post(link.toString(), this.obj, {headers: headers}).subscribe(
   data => {
     console.log(data);
     return data;
   },
   error=> {
    console.error(error);
   }
);
```